# creating very large mysql INSERT query efficiently with C API

Tags: mysql, c, api, insert

I got data in files, which I need to write into a database. I have tried a NoSQL solution, which results in extremely high memory usage. Now I'm trying to get the same thing to work in MySQL using the C API.

The data that needs to be written to the MySQL database is 120+million records. I got it all working basically, but I think the way I create the SQL statements is somewhat slow.

Here is the code that I use:

```
sprintf(queryData, "INSERT INTO table(column1, column2, column3) VALUE");
for (i = 0; i < records; i++){
    sprintf(queryTemp, "(%s,%f,%f)", stringValue, floatValue1, floatValue2);
    strcat(queryData, queryTemp);
}
```

there is some more code in there that adds the "," between the different records.

is there a faster way of creating MySQL queries, than using string manipulation?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is this a one off event?

Comment: Use [prepared statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/c-api-prepared-statement-data-structures.html).  This will be more efficient than generating a new INSERT statement every loop iteration.  Here's an [example](http://www.erickcantwell.com/2011/08/mysql-prepared-statements-in-c/).

Comment: this happens very often as part of reading the source files. I essentially use a databases indexing to trawl through the data. the inserting of the data into MySQL is not a problem at all, but actually creating the SQL statements in the code

Comment: looks like prepared statements is the way to go, but I can't find any good examples. could someone point me into the right direction please? for example for the above query

Answer (score 0):

Since your data is in files you might want to consider using `LOAD DATA INFILE` instead of `INSERT` statements.

> [LOAD DATA INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html)
> The LOAD DATA INFILE statement reads rows from a text file into a table at a very high speed.
>
> [Speed of INSERT Statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-speed.html)
> When loading a table from a text file, use LOAD DATA INFILE. This is
> usually 20 times faster than using INSERT statements. See Section
> 13.2.6, “LOAD DATA INFILE Syntax”.
> ...
> **INSERT is still much slower for loading data than LOAD DATA INFILE**, even when using the strategies just outlined.

Comment: the data that sits in the files is not in SQL format. it needs to be validated as part of the read process. The data must be inserted from an unknown number of clients in the processing cluster.

Comment: @airtruk There is no need for data to be in SQL format. As long as it could be parsed by `LOAD DATA` (meaning line and field terminators are defined deterministically) you could successfully load it. Sometimes (not necessarily in your case) it might be much more efficient to load data into staging area as it is and then validate, clean, normalize etc. using RDBMS toolset.

Comment: interesting, but the files are in binary format and thats where the conversion comes into play when I read them.

Comment: @airtruk Well, even so you might consider doing conversion of files from binary to the format appropriate for `LOAD DATA` using client apps in the processing cluster, pushing files to the db server and loading them. Again not necessarily true for your case (since we know so little about it).